# Contributing to ROS - System Dependency

Tags: ros, dependencies

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to contribute a package to ROS. This is the error that jenkins.ros.org gave back:

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llapack
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

I'm assuming that this is a dependency that needs to be added with a rosdep rule in the manifest. So, I've added the following line to package.xml:

Is this correct?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/138606/contributing-to-ros---system-dependency/) by [atp](https://answers.ros.org/users/5347/atp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 529 on 2014-03-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you have a package.xml, then you have a package using catkin. In this case, there is no "rosdep" key for the package.xml. You need to do

```
 <build_depend>liblapack-dev</build_depend>
```

This will make sure the package is installed when you go to build on the farm -- however, to actually get the linker flags, etc, you will need to probably add the following in your CMakeLists.txt, near the find_package(catkin):

```
find_package(LAPACK REQUIRED)
```

Then, when linking any executable, you'll probably need:

```
target_link_libraries(name_of_target ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${LAPACK_LIBRARIES})
```

(Note: I've not used LAPACK with catkin, so the actual CMAKE may be a bit different, a quick google search shows the find_package call is probably right, but I'm guessing at the name of the _LIBRARIES portion actually exported by LAPACK... I'd check their documentation if things still don't link)

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2014-03-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [atp](https://answers.ros.org/users/5347/atp/) on 2014-03-12**:
Cool. Thanks! That's what I was looking for. I already had the target_link_libraries in my CMakeLists file. This clarified it for me. Let's see how the building goes now on jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a rosdep rule for a package with that exact name, so you should be fine.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-03-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [atp](https://answers.ros.org/users/5347/atp/) on 2014-03-11**:
Thanks! Where do I put that line? If I put it inside of "", then catkin_make shows: The manifest must not contain the following tags: rosdep. If it is put outside, catkin_make gives: junk after document element: line 37, column 0.

**Comment by [atp](https://answers.ros.org/users/5347/atp/) on 2014-03-11**:
http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0127.html indicates that: <build_depend> (multiple) Declares a rosdep key or ROS package name that this package requires at build-time. (And it shows the same for run_depend). Is this the right way to go? I'm somewhat confused right now ...